# Can't use Data Profiling Queries and Charts using airflow sqlite DB?

Tags: airflow

Installed airflow and am using the default sqlite DB. Finding that the Data Profiling Ad Hoc Query and Charts features do not work. Eg. in the Ad Hoc Query UI, setting the interpreter to sqlite_default and doing something like

```sql
select * from task_instance;
```

throws

> Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM ( select * from task_instance ) qry LIMIT 100000 ': no such table: task_instance
>
> No data

and attempting to view the chart with label "Airflow task instance by type" throws

```sql
SELECT state, COUNT(1) as number FROM task_instance WHERE dag_id LIKE 'example%' GROUP BY state
```

> SQL execution failed. Details: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_pandas_df'

(clicking the pen icon in this screen just takes me to the mushroom cloud error screen).

Anyone know what is happening with this and how to fix while still using sqlite DB?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put '/Users/{your_name}/airflow/airflow.db' in the host field of the Admin -> Connections.